# The rules of the game vs. the laws of the game

Tags: differences

Do *rule* and *law* have the same meaning when you talk about an activity like a game?

I came across this sentence in the Collins Cobuild Advanced Learner's Dictionay:

"Match officials should not tolerate such behaviour but instead enforce the laws of the game."

I've heard "the rules of the game" a lot and wonder what the word "law" refers to in this sentence. Is it the same as *rule*? Can you use the word "rule" in the sentence, without any change in meaning?

Comment: "Rules of the game" is a "set phrase" in English, often used as a metaphor -- eg, someone may apply the phrase to romance.  As stated below, "law" implies a stricter, more formal restriction than does a "rule", though there's no strict "test" as to when one should be applied vs the other (except that, of course, governmentally edicted rules are almost always called "laws").

Comment: (The above-quoted sentence is a bit odd to an American ear, BTW.  Presuming the "match" is a game of sport, the regulations governing such are almost always referred to as "rules".  "Laws" would only be such things as governmental regulations covering participant safety.)

Comment: @HotLicks So when talking about games we use rules right? The definition in the Collins Cobuild Dictionary is "The laws of an organization or activity are its rules, which are used to organize and control it.", and then the quoted sentence is given as an example. What do you think?

Comment: Normally one (in the US) would use "rules" in the above sentence.  "Laws" would not be technically wrong, but could be confusing in some cases.  One suspects that the authors of the dictionary were "stretching" to find an example that fit their needs in that case.

Comment: As mentioned by [Tim](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218043/the-rules-of-the-game-vs-the-laws-of-the-game#comment464757_218073): **cricket**!

Comment: FIFA's website also refers to the laws of football <a href="http://www.fifa.com/about-fifa/official-documents/law-regulations/">here</a>, and publishes the laws <a href="http://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/02/79/92/44/laws.of.the.game.2016.2017_neutral.pdf"> here</a>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule is defined as "an accepted principle or instruction that states the way things are or should be done, and tells you what you are allowed or are not allowed to do" (Source: Cambridge Dictionaries). Rules carry lower consequences than a law and can be agreed and adjusted by concerned parties.
Laws are like legal versions of rules.As the rules which are enforceable fall under the definition of law "enforce the laws of the game" was used in that sentence. These laws in professional sport are enforceable and players must follow them.

Answer (score 6):

No.

A [law is a rule](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/law) that specifies what you can and can't do.

> The main [difference between rules and laws](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-rules-and-laws/) is the consequences
>   associated with breaking them. While each is developed to invoke a
>   sense of order, fair play, and safety, the weight of a law is much
>   heavier than the weight of a rule.

Laws are like the legal version of rules.

- speed limit laws

> When you are a child, a parent sets **rules** to be followed. When you are
>   in a society, the government sets **laws** to be followed.

When a rule is broken, the consequences tend to be uncomfortable but mild in comparison to the breaking of a law.

- classroom rules

Answer (score 3):

At NGrams, I tried a few combinations.  Usually, "rules" far outnumbers "laws" for games.  But I did find this one:  In British English, "laws of cricket" seems relatively prevalent...

[LINK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laws%20of%20cricket%2Crules%20of%20cricket&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Claws%20of%20cricket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crules%20of%20cricket%3B%2Cc0)
[image: laws]

Comment: So far as I know, cricket is unique in having *Laws* rather than *rules*; omitting the capital letter is a minor solecism, but miscalling them is major.

Comment: Hardly unique. Bridge, for example, is a card game with [Laws](http://www.acbl.org/acbl-content/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Laws-of-Duplicate-Bridge.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

For sports, the choice between "laws" and "rules" is essentially a fairly arbitrary one made by that sport's governing body in the dim and distant past. For example, Rugby and Soccer have "laws", but Golf and Tennis have "rules".

There is no practical difference, though it's preferable to use to correct term for each sport if you wish to appear knowledgable.

Answer (score 2):

Rugby union is governed by laws and not rules.   Just go to any clubhouse in the UK and say rugby rules and you will immediately be corrected.    I think it's silly really.   I see laws not enforced so they are rules in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The *rules* of golf are objective, the *laws* of football are subjective and open to interpretation eg *was that a deliberate hand ball?*

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I thought handball was objectively defined, just as whether a ball is out or not in tennis. It can be just as difficult to determine whether a ball was out as it is to determine whether a handball occurred. I'm not sure that objectivity or subjectivity determines whether a sport is governed by laws or rules. However, you may well be right: some corroboration of your assertion would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Rules are narrow, laws take in a wider aspect. In rugby the law book says kick off is to be at or behind the centre of the halfway line. If this were a rule, then there would be a ref's whistle at just about every kick off if even a centimetre either side. Whereas Laws of The Game have "effective" in the application where the "spirit" of the game is included. Play on. Similarly if a player steps offside when ball is at bottom of a ruck, ref will just tell the player to get back, and if he has not interfered with play, then play on, if a a rule, ref would have to whistle.